# JSP/Javascript/JQuery: store html/javascript content in a variable + write it to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, character-encoding

I'm using a json object to store different bits of content, one of which can contain javascript & html relevant content (like quotes, semicolons,  tags etc) which without encoding can break the page. To work around this I'm using:

"content":"<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(content))%>"

(I'm using JSP as server-side technology and this is a bit of the JSON generated inline when the page is loading)

This works fine to escape any character that might break the page, but I now need to get the content from this variable to a textarea.

$('textarea').val(obj.content);

What I'm trying to avoid is the double-encoding that happens at this point:

- the original content is: `<script>alert("hello world");</script>`
- the content variable holds: `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;hello world&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;`
- the text in the textarea reads: `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;hello world&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;` when it should read `<script>alert("hello world");</script>`

Any way of making this work?

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('textarea').html(obj.content);` ?

In my tests, using the `html` function instead of `val` does the HTML entity decoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in unescape. I mean $('textarea').val(unescape(obj.content));

Comment: unescape() has no effect on the content.

Comment: Yes you are rigth:( sorry - than you need to htmp entity decode manually.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` instead? If the JSON is in a `<script>` block that should be sufficient to avoid breaking the page and no decoding will be necessary.

Comment: That's how it was originally, but because there exists the unencoded "</script>" element in my content, it prematurely closes the <script> containing the JSON.